# Different typeof 'this' when calling/applying a strict function vs. a non-strict function

Tags: javascript, node.js

It looks like when I'm using `func.call(12)` on some non-strict function `func`, it will use `this = new Number(12)` instead of `this = 12` (see the snippet below). I noticed because `typeof this` was equal to `'object'` instead of `'number'`.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there any way around it?

```js
function a() {
  return this;
}

function b() {
  'use strict';
  return this;
}

const x = a.call(12);
console.log(typeof x);
console.log(x);
console.log(x + 3);

const y = b.call(12);
console.log(typeof y);
console.log(y);
console.log(y + 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this expected behaviour?

Yes, it's expected behaviour. In sloppy mode, `this` is always an object - casting primitives to their respective wrapper objects. And worse, `null` and `undefined` get replaced with the global object.

> Is there any way around it?

Just always use strict mode.