# Why doesn't `this` returned from bound function strictly equal passed primitive value?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that `this` returned from bound function doesn't strictly equal primitive value passed when binding.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description) when the original function is called `[[BoundThis]]` gets passed.

What is `this` returned from bound function? Is it `[[BoundThis]]`?

```js
const fn = function() { return this }
const strBound = fn.bind('111')
const numBound = fn.bind(111)
const boolBound = fn.bind(true)

console.log(strBound()) // [String: '111']
console.log(strBound() == '111') // true
console.log(strBound() === '111') // false

console.log(numBound()) // [Number: 111]
console.log(numBound() == 111) // true
console.log(numBound() === 111) // false

console.log(boolBound()) // [Boolean: true]
console.log(boolBound() == true) // true
console.log(boolBound() === true) // false
```

Comment: It answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour, as always, has been defined by the ECMAScript specification. In this case it takes a while to actually follow the different specifications, but if you are interested in the details, here you go.

> ### 19.2.3.2 [Function.prototype.bind ( thisArg , ...args)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind)
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Let F be **BoundFunctionCreate**(Target, thisArg, args).
>
> [...]
>
> 16. Return F.
>
> ---
>
> ### 9.4.1.3 [BoundFunctionCreate (targetFunction, boundThis, boundArgs)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boundfunctioncreate)
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Set the **[[Call]]** internal method of obj as described in 9.4.1.1.
>
> ---
>
> ### 9.4.1.1 [`[[Call]]` ( thisArgument, argumentsList)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Return **Call**(target, boundThis, args).
>
> ---
>
> ### 7.3.12 [Call(F, V, [argumentsList])](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-call)
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Return F.**[[Call]]**(V, argumentsList).
>
> ---
>
> ### 9.2.1 [`[[Call]]` ( thisArgument, argumentsList)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Perform **OrdinaryCallBindThis**(F, calleeContext, thisArgument).
>
> ---
>
> ### 9.2.1.2 [OrdinaryCallBindThis ( F, calleeContext, thisArgument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis)
>
> [...]
>
> 5. If thisMode is strict, let thisValue be thisArgument.
> 6. Else
>
>    - if thisArgument is null or undefined, then
>        Let thisValue be calleeRealm.[[globalThis]].
>    - Else
>        Let thisValue be **ToObject**(thisArgument).
>
> ---
>
> ### 7.1.13 [ToObject ( argument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)
>
> [...]
>
> Number: Return a new Number object whose [[NumberData]] internal slot is set to the value of argument. See 20.1 for a description of Number objects.
>
> String: Return a new String object whose [[StringData]] internal slot is set to the value of argument. See 21.1 for a description of String objects.

- A primitive string is not strictly equal to a string object with the same value.
- A primitive number is not strictly equal to a number object with the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not in strict mode, which means it will always implicitly cast its received `this` value to an object (and uses the global object upon receiving `null`/`undefined`). Your code will work as expected with

```
function fn() {
    "use strict";
    return this;
}
```

Notice that [one could reproduce the issue without `bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555313/different-typeof-this-when-calling-applying-a-strict-function-vs-a-non-strict/).

Answer (score 1):

Binding a function to a string primitive implicitly converts the string primitive into a String object.

When type coercion is in play, a string primitive and String object will match.

Without type coercion, they won't.

Ditto other kinds of primitives.

```js
const prim = "x";
const obj = new String("x");

console.log(prim instanceof String);
console.log(obj instanceof String);
console.log(prim == obj);
console.log(prim === obj);
```

Comment: The first sentence is objectively wrong. Binding the function doesn't convert anything.